# I have no idea about where I should place config.json file in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using [`gem 'google_drive'`](https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby).
This gem provides functions to manipulate Google Drive Files.
First of all, I have to create `config.json` as below

```
{
  "client_id": "my-client-id",
  "client_secret": "my-client-secret"
}
```

And, Authenticate with

```
session = GoogleDrive::Session.from_config("path/to/config.json")
```

Then, config.json will be rewritten as below

```
{
  "client_id": "my-client-id",
  "client_secret": "my-client-secret",
  "scope": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
    "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/"
  ],
  "refresh_token": "refresh-token"
}
```

I don't wanna place `config.json` in the root of my application.

---

### **Where is the best place to put `config.json`?**

**I was thinking about putting it in config/config.json**

This seems like a good place to me.
But, on the other hand, I think the config directory should contain files that will not be changed while application is running, and config.json will be rewritten by `GoogleDrive` while application is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think you should use config.json in a rails app.

You use config.json when you want to do authorization via the command line, but that doesn't make much sense in a web app.

Instead, you probably should redirect the user to an authorization web page.

Take a look at the second method here:(https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby/blob/master/doc/authorization.md)